# How to setup matching rules and duplicate rules to check for email on 2 fields?

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

So, we have 2 fields on contact and lead:

- Email
- Alternate Email

To make sure they are not the same on the record, a simple validation rule is enough.

However, we want to disabled creating other records, but to also check email =/= alternate email.

This is not working, since it always checks the same field to it self.

[image]

I want that if a new lead is created, with john@doe.com
and another lead/contact has john@doe.com as an alternate email, the duplicate alert will popup.

thanks

Comment: you won't be able to do this with the out of box functionality - see this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cHBJAA2).

Comment: Shame it's not possible OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with a simple flow and another field.

- Create a field on the lead/contact object that holds it's own CASESAFEID (not a formula)
- every time a lead is saved, (email changed) look for other records that have the email as the 'Alternate email' field.
- If found - set the record with the email 'Duped Index' with the ID of the Duped record that has the alternative email.
- A matching rule will not identify both records as duplicates.

Thought: You can also add a new duplicate rule to not allow this edit